# Ask Users to Input the Date using the YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: php, mysql, html

Good day!

I am new to programming and I am a little confused how to ask users to input the date in a web page

I have the form below to ask for dates:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
   <form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input name="event_startDate" type="text" id="event_startDate" size="17">
        <input name="event_endDate" type="text" id="event_endDate" size="17">
        <input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" id="submit" value="ADD EVENT">
    </form>
```

The format of Mysql is YYYY-MM-DD so I've decided to use it. Now I need to ask the users to input using the YYYY-MM-DD format.

I can just insert the YYYY-MM-DD in the text box but I want the start date to be the date today so instead  I plan to this:

[image]

My problem is.... I don't know how. How can i insert the date in the textbox with that format using PHP? Can i add a value? But if i add the value, will it change also when the user decided to change the value and press the submit button? Also, how can I do it wherein the hypen (-) is not needed to be edited... I mean it will stay as is and the user just need to input the numbers       `-  -`  .

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format a date, in PHP, using the [**`date()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Then, to pre-fill the data in your form, just put that date in the `value` attribute of your `<input>` field :

```
<input type="text" name="date1" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

This will act as default value.

When the form is submitted, you will receive the date that was in the field when the form has been submitted -- be it the default date, or anything else the user could have typed.

A couple of additional notes :

- You might want to use some widget, a bit more user-friendly ; for instance [jQuery's Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).
- In any case, don't forget to validate the user input :

  - Correct format
  - Valid date

Comment: but how can the I make the hyphen stay in place?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stay in place" ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a more user-friendly solution like for example a [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

You can set the [date-format](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) to the format you want without having to bother your users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend using a Date Picker, but you could also split the date box into 3 select boxes, 1-31, 1-12, 2011-2015 etc, so the user can just select the date from the box. I prefer the Date Picker one though. You can then format the data in any way you want.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use input type as a date format:

```
<input type="date" name="event_startDate">
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question(s)